# Why can't we uncensor all editions of Sefer Vayikra?

Tags: jewish-books, rabbis, sefer-vayikra

I heard according to our sages of blessed memory that certain editions of Sefer Vayikra were censored in Europe, because it says in Sefer Vayikra when the end comes Edom (The West/Christianity) will be defeated by Paras (Iran), so when Christians in certain areas of Europe found out about it our sages of blessed memory had to censor Sefer Vayikra in fear of Christian retribution, by changing Edom (The West/Christianity) being defeated by Paras (Iran) to Paras (Iran being defeated by (The West/Christianity), so why can't all editions of Sefer Vayikra that were censored be uncensored now a days since we are no longer under threat by Christian retribution in our current day in age.

Comment: What censorship do you mean. Do you mean the censored parts of the **Talmud**? The Torah itself was never censored.

Comment: To clarify, there was indeed much censorship; often self-censorship, in Christian Europe, out of fear of offending the Church authorities. However, there were no changes to the Torah as part of this. What were often changed, were prayers and poems; often beseeching God to save them from, and defeat, their enemies. This sounds closest to the the sort of textual changes you are describing, and I am guessing, that this is what you originally heard.

Comment: I think you mean "אמר רבי יוחנן משום ר' יהודה ברבי אלעאי עתידה רומי שתפול ביד פרס קל וחומר ומה מקדש ראשון שבנאוהו בני שם והחריבוהו כשדיים נפלו כשדיים ביד פרסיים מקדש שני שבנאוהו פרסיים והחריבוהו רומיים אינו דין שיפלו רומיים ביד פרסיים"

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%90_%D7%99_%D7%90

Comment: @ShmuelBrin I edited with your link

Comment: @kouty editing the answers into questions just confused everybody. It also hurts readability.

Comment: @kouty certainly you shouldn't totally change the question without asking the op.especially when he is still active here.

Comment: What censorship do you mean. Do you mean the censored parts of the Talmud? The Torah itself was never censored. – sabbahillel 11 hours ago _____________________ sabbahillel Yes – arthurlerner 8 hours ago

Answer (score 1):

Your premise is mistaken. The Torah/Bible was never censored. This has been proven by the fact that modern Jewish Torahs scrolls closely match the writings of the Dead Sea Scrolls. The Dead Sea Scrolls are recognized by all scholarly authorities to predate Christianity by several hundred years. And while there are minor differences between our current writings and the Dead Sea Scrolls, none of those differences have to do with censorship from Christianity.

For more info see: http://www.deadseascrolls.org.il/learn-about-the-scrolls/introduction

Comment: Yeah I was wondering. To my knowledge Torah has never been censored. Ever.